# Similarity between Sets containing Integers in java or groovy

Tags: java, groovy, comparison, similarity

I have `HashSet<Integer>` `A` and `B` I want to compare to get a numeric value how similar they are (e.g. 0.9 if 90% of `A` and `B` are the same). What is the best (fastest) way to do this in java or groovy?

My naive way to do this is to get all equal elements from `A` and `B` and divide the size of them through the original size of `A`. Is there any reason (speed e.g.) why this wouldn't work properly? Generally speaking I would prefer any already implemented way to get the similarity.

Note: Comparing `1, 2` to `12` should be 0% similarity.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by similar, you could use take the count of the intersect divided by the count of the union.

Comment: Using the intersection and union did it for me. If you want you can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Adam suggests, a loop is the most efficient way to find the size of the intersection

```
public static int intersectionsCount(Set set1, Set set2) {
    if (set2.size() < set1.size()) return intersectionsCount(set2, set1);
    int count = 0;
    for (Object o : set1)
        if (set2.contains(o)) count++;
    return count;
}

public static double commonRatio(Set set1, Set set2) {
    int common = intersectionsCount(set1, set2);
    int union = set1.size() + set2.size() - common;
    return (double) common / union; // [0.0, 1.0]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to calculate the similarity of 2 arbitrary HashSets of size M and N is to choose the smallest one and check if its elements are present in a bigger one. There is no such method in JDK. If you're looking for the fastest solution, write your own:

```
int count = 0;
for (E element : smallSet) {
    if (bigSet.contains(element) {
       count++;
    }
}
```

If you don't care much about performance and extra memory, you can use

```
int count = new HashSet(smallSet).retainAll(bigSet);
```

or similar method `Sets#intersection(Set, Set)` from  [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) library